# How to use Sparkline in function react with Highcharts.js/highcharts-react-official?

Tags: reactjs, highcharts

I want to create a sparklines graph in react using Highcharts. What I've found so far is implemented in vanilla javascript/jquery and class-based react. Is there a functional way to do this?

Comment: Hi @importTurtle, It depends on what exactly you want to create, but creating sparklines charts in React using Highcharts is almost the same as in plain JS. Please check this simple live example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-8simfq?file=/demo.jsx and let me know if you need more help.

Comment: @ppotaczek thx for that demo  i understand like maybe 25% of it but it was enough to get what I wanted to work, I think I don't know how JavaScript and react work well enough. If you have any tips I'd be happy to listen. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I am glad that I could help. It is impossible to share any valuable tips only by a comment on SO. I recommend you do some online JS/React course. React is just a JS framework, so it is better to get to know JS first.